# Transforming to Database Layout, VLookup, Round, Months

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Good Morning My Friends. How are you all?

So i need Help with Excel Formula.

[image]

I have a Table just like Above , with a lot of Contract Numbers and how much those contracts will pay me monthly.

So I May receive the same value from Month 1 to Month 60 as Contract 1 shows, or this value may escalate, just like Contract 182, which ill receive 13.946,56 during 2 years, than ill receive 15065 monthly for the 3 remaining years. Another ex may be Contract 49 which ill receive in the first year 5.694, than in the second year 6.514, and this escalates every year.

What I need is to Transpose it in another Tab as a "Database" Layout:

[image]

In these Tab i need the "Months" showed as Years, and Every Contract have to show the value that will pay me Monthly for FIVE YEARS(Years One to Five).

Theres no Problem to Round the Year (Exemple Month 14 may be Year 1 and 19 May be Year 2).

All contracts have different numbers.

Tried Something like this, didn't solve:

```
=IF(ROUND(RIGHT(VLOOKUP(R56;Consolidado!Q:BC;2;0);2);0)/12>=S56;V55;VLOOKUP(C56;Consolidado!Q:BC;19+S56-S55+1))
```

[image]

Does anyone has a tip?

Comment: Contract 1 is duplicated.

Comment: Its a Typo error... may consider the second contract as "1-A" and not "1"

Answer (score -1):

Taking the folders as an example:
A: Contacts: 1/2 / 3 / ...
B: Months: "1 to 14" / "1 to 60" / ...
C: Value: 5000/2000 / ...
D: Months Level 2: "15 to 60" / ...
E: Value Level 2: 8000 / ...

then...

G column with title "Limit Months"

```
=IF(B2="";"";VALUE(MID(B2;FIND(" a ";$B2)+3;99)))
```

H column with title "Div"

```
=IF(G2="";0;ROUND(G2/12;0))
```

I column with title "Limit Months"

```
=IF(D2="";"";VALUE(MID(D2;FIND(" a ";$D2)+3;99))-G2)
```

J column with title "Div"

```
=IF(I2="";0;ROUND(I2/12;0))
```

K column with title "Indices" <- IMPORTANT

```
=IF(K1="Indices";"1-0";IFERROR(IF(VALUE(MID(K1;FIND("-";K1)+1;99))<INDEX($H$2:$H$1000;MATCH(VALUE(LEFT(K1;(FIND("-";K1))-1));$A$2:$A$1000;0));MID(K1;1;FIND("-";K1))&VALUE(MID(K1;FIND("-";K1)+1;99))+1;VALUE(MID(K1;1;FIND("-";K1)-1)+1)&"-0");VALUE(MID(K1;1;FIND("-";K1)-1))+1&"-0"))
```

L column with title "Val1"

```
=IF(VALUE(MID(K2;FIND("-";K2)+1;99))<>0;INDEX($C$2:$C$10000;MATCH(VALUE(MID(K2;1;FIND("-";K2)-1));$A$2:$A$1000;0));"")
```

M column with title "Indices2" <- IMPORTANT

```
=IF(M1="Indices2";"1-0";IFERROR(IF(VALUE(MID(M1;FIND("-";M1)+1;99))<INDEX($J$2:$J$1000;MATCH(VALUE(LEFT(M1;(FIND("-";M1))-1));$A$2:$A$1000;0));MID(M1;1;FIND("-";M1))&VALUE(MID(M1;FIND("-";M1)+1;99))+1;VALUE(MID(M1;1;FIND("-";M1)-1)+1)&"-0");VALUE(MID(M1;1;FIND("-";M1)-1))+1&"-0"))
```

N column with title "Val2"

```
=IF(VALUE(MID(M2;FIND("-";M2)+1;99))<>0;INDEX($E$2:$E$10000;MATCH(VALUE(MID(M2;1;FIND("-";M2)-1));$A$2:$A$1000;0));"")
```

Here an example:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rZnhC6-H4xm4AD4uRgsCWJZ7p7oVBZtU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Worth the Shot, thanks, but it didn't Solve. I have some complications:

Contracts may not be just Numbers, they may be formed by numbers+Letters or Symbols, just like:
276A or 233-1 or even A233

And i may not use differents Columns with values... I must have all the values in just one column... May not also have more than one "Index" column...